# How to replace and save a word in text file using regular expression in python

Tags: python-2.7

Here is my program I want to replace a word to another word in a text file using a regular expression but I am not able to save those words in the text file. Can anyone, please help me to save a file. Thank you in advance.

Given below is my code:

```
import re
with open("c:\Users\Desktop\hh.txt","r+") as f:
     for i in f.readlines():
        content=re.sub("hai","welcome",i)
        #after replace  how can i save these words in text file again
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple approach for small files is to do your reading and writing separately.

```
import re

path = 'hh.txt'

with open(path, "r") as f:
    oldlines = f.readlines()

newlines = []

for line in oldlines:
    newlines.append(re.sub("hai", "welcome", line))

with open(path, "w") as f:
    f.writelines(newlines)
```

If you're dealing with huge files, I suggest you write to a temporary file while reading from your input file. Then do a file delete then a file rename.